# How to use get_template part in the plugin?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, templates, page-template

I was using the entire template in the plugin, but I would like to use get template part, so that I can reuse the header and footer in the original template. The code is like this:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'template_reg' );
function template_reg()
{
  if ( is_page( ourdoctors_single_pg() ) ) {       
  $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ).'/templates/OurDoctors.php';
  return $page_template;       
}
```

Is there any way that I can use partial template instead of entire template? I tried to use `get_template_part`, but it seems like I have to put template in the theme. But how to put the template in the plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) will always look in the theme. It uses [`locate_template`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L128) which is [hard-coded to use `STYLESHEETPATH` and `TEMPLATETPATH`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/template.php#L373)

I don't know exactly what you mean about using a "partial template", but if you mean "can I include part of a PHP file?" then no. It is all or nothing. You need to break your file into multiple files or break the file's contents into granular functions that you can call as needed.